# What should I use for wireless communication between an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, wifi, arduino, communication

I have several devices like sensor, motor, etc which are connected to the Arduino. I want to transfer my sensor data from the Arduino to the Raspberry Pi wirelessly.

Also, all the data from different sensors connected to the Arduino should be gathered by one device which is attached to the Raspberry Pi.

What should be used for this?

Answer (score 3):

The most common wireless communications for arduino/Pi/sensors are:

- Wifi
- RF (something like a 433Mhz Tx/Rx module)
- Bluetooth

Those are simply the communication channel and any/all will work - the differences between them are range, speed, power requirements and how you interface with them.
You will also need to decide upon a message transfer protocol between the arduino (presuambly these are collecting the data from the sensors) and the 'server' (presumably the Pi)

For example - how will the server know which sensor the data came from, how will you signal error conditions at the sensor, what if a sensor cannot 'reach' the server (offline etc) - does it throw away the measurement or store it for transmission later?

One possible approach could be to use WiFi and something like MQTT which provides for a lot of the communications layer challenges mentioned above.

You might want to read about some of the [stuff this guy is doing with ESP8226, MQTT and Raspberry Pis](http://tech.scargill.net/)

Good luck...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an [Arduino WiFi Shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield) would solve your problem. You would also need a WiFi dongle for your Raspberry Pi.